# How do I `expect` something which raises exception in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have a method which performs some actions on Cat model and in case of incorrect input raises an exception:

```
context "hungry cat" do
  it { expect { eat(what: nil) }.to raise_error } 
end
```

What I want to do is to check whether this method change cats status, like that:

```
context "hungry cat" do
  it { expect { eat(what: nil) }.to raise_error } 
  it { expect { eat(what: nil) }.not_to change(cat, :status) } 
end
```

The problem is that since `eat(what: nil)` will raise an exception the second `it` will fail no matter what. So, is it possible to ignore exception and check some condition?

I know that it's possible to do something like:

```
it do 
  expect do
    begin
      eat(what: nil)
    rescue
    end
  end.not_to change(cat, :status)
end
```

But it's way too ugly.

Comment: In `Test/Unit`, there is a nice assertion, `assert_raise`, I think.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could use the "rescue nil" idiom to shorten what you already have:

```
it { expect { eat(what: nil) rescue nil }.not_to change(cat, :status) }
```

Comment: This works, but I wish there was an rspec way of doing this, e.g.: `expect { ... }.ignoring_errors.to change(cat, :status)`

Comment: `ignoring_errors` doesn't seem to work in RSpec 3.9 `undefined method ignoring_errors for #<RSpec::Expectations::BlockExpectationTarget:0x00007fabbca91978>`

Comment: @Sig I think that's expected. Here, Matt Huggins was making a suggestion for a feature, not listing an existing method.

Answer (score 47):

You can [chain](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/compound-expectations) positive assertions with `and`. If you want to mix in a negated one in the chain, RSpec 3.1 introduced [`define_negated_matcher`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/define-negated-matcher).

You could do something like:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :not_change, :change

expect { eat(what: nil) }
  .to raise_error
  .and not_change(cat, :status)
```

Inspired by [this comment](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/664#issuecomment-58134735).

Comment: Please note that with this approach, you end up with two expectations in one example. See http://www.betterspecs.org/#single

Answer (score 9):

In RSpec 3 you can chain the two tests into one. I find this to be more readable than the `rescue nil` approach.

`it { expect { eat(what: nil) }.to raise_error.and  not_to change(cat, :status)}`

Comment: Are you sure this is the right syntax? It gives me error: `NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'not_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::` on rspec 3.4.4

Comment: This syntax is incorrect. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882831/1020168 for the correct syntax and explanation.

See also:

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/compound-expectations
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/define-negated-matcher

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange that the `eat(what: nil)` code isn't run in isolation for each of your tests and is affecting the others.  I'm not sure, but perhaps re-writing the tests slightly will either solve the issue or more accurately identify where the problem is (pick your flavour below).

Using `should`:

```
context "hungry cat" do
  context "when not given anything to eat" do
    subject { -> { eat(what: nil) } }
    it { should raise_error } 
    it { should_not change(cat, :status) }
  end
end
```

Using `expect`:

```
context "hungry cat" do
  context "when not given anything to eat" do
    let(:eating_nothing) { -> { eat(what: nil) } }
    it "raises an error" do
      expect(eating_nothing).to raise_error
    end
    it "doesn't change cat's status" do
      expect(eating_nothing).to_not change(cat, :status)
    end 
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. If `eat` raises an exception the second case will always fail because exception being unhanded.

Comment: Perhaps I did.  Is it expected behaviour in your system to have unhandled exceptions that your users can potentially generate?  If so, could you explain why, either here or in an edit to your question?

Comment: Yes, it is of course expected behaviour, moreover most ruby libraries can generate exceptions which should be handled by their users and this behaviour should be tested too. E.g. rails `#save!`, `Float('aaa')`, EOFError during `File#read`. What I want to test in my case is that context was successfully restored after exception was thrown (transaction rolled back, descriptors closed, etc).

Comment: @Paul Fioravanti "doesn't change cat's status" will still raise exception

Answer (score 0):

You can also put expectations inside expectation blocks. It's still a *little* ugly, but it should work:

```rb
expect do
  # including the error class is just good practice
  expect { cat.eat(what: nil) }.to raise_error(ErrorClass) 
end.not_to change { cat.status }
```